# what is the use of the bot's name in Python ChatterBot?

Tags: python, nlp, chatbot, chatterbot

```
from chatterbot import ChatBot

# Create a new chat bot named Charlie
chatbot = ChatBot('Charlie')
```

what is the use of the bot's name "Charlie"? Can my chatbot know his name in a group chat, and only reply message about him?

```
-- "Hi, Charlie"
- bot: "Hi"
-- "Charlie, tell me the time"
- bot: "It's nine o'clock"
-- "how are you?"
- ...
```

I have read the doc but find nothing about it, say thanks advanced if you guys tell me how to approach it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From what I have seen from their ChatBot.py, the constructor requires "name" as the only parameter.

I am unable to find anything in the documentation that addresses it and I can neither test it as of now, but based on [1], it appears that upon generating an answer, it is used to define the "persona" parameter for the Statement constructor.
Upon looking into the Stament [2] constructor, it seems that the "persona" parameter might be a string identifying who generated the statement.

---

[1]https://github.com/gunthercox/ChatterBot/blob/4ff8af28567ed446ae796d37c246bb6a14032fe7/chatterbot/chatterbot.py#L203

[2] https://github.com/gunthercox/ChatterBot/blob/4ff8af28567ed446ae796d37c246bb6a14032fe7/chatterbot/conversation.py#L64

Comment: this does not answer the question. Moreover, the information you give about the column "persona" is wrong. It does not carry the name given to the chatbot. Which, in fact does not appear anywere in the DB. (Except of course if it happens to be included in the text, as part of the chat).